# Adding DbContext into existing .net 4 application

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have existing .net 4 application which is based on object context.
Now I'm adding DbContext in to existing application by inheriting DbContext and call constructor method and pass the existing object context. i.e.

```
public class DemoModelEntitiesDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DemoModelEntitiesDbContext():base(new DemoModelEntities(), dbContextOwnsObjectContext:true)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<ELMAH_Error> ELMAH_Error { get; set; }
    }
```

Than When I call,

```
using (DemoModelEntitiesDbContext context = new DemoModelEntitiesDbContext())
            {
                foreach (ELMAH_Error entity in context.ELMAH_Error.ToList())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(entity.ID);
                }
}
```

I am getting following error message,
"The type 'ObjectContextDemo.ELMAH_Error' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject."
I checked my existing entities are inheriting from EntityObject.
How to add DbContext in to existing application and not changing existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast to object context but then you gain nothing from DbContext if you 100% stick with existing code. but Ive done that with POCOs, not EntityObjects and can't confirm that it would work with entityobjects.

Otherwise it's not possible to do that without changes. DbContext does not support EntityObject. DbContext is designed for POCOs. Plus there are other code differences between DbContext and ObjectContext. You'd have to change even if you were already using POCOs. If you are using the EF designer, you'd have to start by using a different code gen template (ef5 DbContext template). But that will result in very different classes and plenty of changes to your EF calls in your app.